# If $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0 = 0$ has a rational root, then such root is an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $n > 0$ and let $a_{n-1}, ..., a_0$ be integers. Prove that, if $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0 = 0$ has a rational root, then such root is an integer.

I understand that posting questions without showing your work is frowned upon, but I don't know where to start with this one.. thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you substitute $x \mapsto p/q$ for $p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: This is a direct result of [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: @rtybase I'm not familiar with that result, thanks. I'll check it out.

Comment: You will find similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534745/suppose-alpha-is-a-rational-root-of-a-monic-polynomial-in-mathbbzx-pr) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675260/equation-and-polynomial).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote the rational root by $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p\in\mathbb{Z},q\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$. We have:

$\frac{p^n}{q^n}+a_{n-1}\frac{p^{n-1}}{q^{n-1}}+...+a_0=0$

Multiply the equation by $q^n$. Then we get:

$p^n+qa_{n-1}p^{n-1}+q^2a_{n-2}p^{n-2}+...+q^na_0=0$

This implies that $q$ divides $p^n$. But since $\gcd(p,q)=1$ we also have $\gcd(p^n,q)=1$, and hence if $q$ divides $p^n$ then $q=1$.

Comment: It's interesting how a proof becomes "obvious" after you learn it.. I was staring at this problem for some 15 minutes and came up with nothing.